# Change Background COlor CHip depends User , if Admin or not

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

what I want is to change the background color of the chip depending on whether user admin or not, a different color for each user, in the list of comments, so that the end user can define who is the admin and who is not.

**this is my code**

```
import React from 'react';
import TimeAgo from 'react-timeago';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import Card from 'components/commons/Card';
import Chip from '@material-ui/core/Chip';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import { Grid  } from '@material-ui/core';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { getComments } from 'api'

const styles = {
  root: {
    paddingTop: '25px',
    color: '#FFFFFF'
  },
  chipA: {
    color: 'white',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    backgroundColor: '#00a6ff',
    textTransform: 'uppercase',
    fontSize: '1rem',
    letterSpacing: '0px',
    textAlign: 'center'
  },
  chipB: {
    color: 'primary',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    backgroundColor: '#ff8400',
    textTransform: 'uppercase',
    fontSize: '1rem',
    letterSpacing: '0px',
    textAlign: 'center'
  },
  Button: {
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    fontSize: '1rem',
    letterSpacing: '0px',
    textTransform: 'uppercase',
    borderRadius: '2.5px',
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
};

class Comment extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      comment: '',
      isAdmin: [],
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log(this.props.isAdmin)
    if (this.props.isAdmin) { 
      console.log('Admin User'); 
      }else {
      console.log('Normal User');
      }
    };

  onChange = e => {
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  }

  renderComments(comments) {
    const condition = this.props.isAdmin;
    console.log(condition);

    const commentDivs = comments.map(user => {
      return (
        <div key={user.id}>
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col comment">{user.description}</div>
          </div>
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col-9">
              <TimeAgo className="time-ago" date={user.createdAt} />
            </div>
            <div className="col-3">
              <div style={styles.wrapper}>
                <span className="time-ago">
                  <Chip
                    label={user['user.firstname'] + ' ' + user['user.lastname']}
                    style={{ backgroundColor: condition ? "#00a6ff" : "#ff8400" , color: 'white', fontWeight: 'bold',
                    textTransform: 'uppercase',
                    fontSize: '1rem',
                    letterSpacing: '0px',
                    textAlign: 'center'}}
                  />
                </span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <hr />
        </div>
      )
    });
    return (
      <div>{commentDivs}</div>
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Card title="comments">
        <Grid item xs={12} md={12}>
          {this.renderComments(this.props.comments)}
          <div className="form-group">
            <textarea
              className="form-control"
              name="comment"
              placeholder="Write a comment"
              onChange={this.onChange}
              value={this.state.comment}
              rows="3"
            ></textarea>
          </div>
          <div className="form-group">
            <Button
              onClick={() => this.props.onSubmit(this.state.comment)}
              color="primary"
              variant="contained"
              size="large"
              style={styles.Button}>
              Send
             </Button>
          </div>
        </Grid>
      </Card>
    );
  }
}

Comment.propTypes = {
  comments: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
  onSubmit: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  isAdmin: PropTypes.bool,
};

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    isAdmin: state.auth.isAdmin,
  };
};

export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, { 
})(Comment)) ;
```

what I define is that I change the color depends on who is registered, but what you want is to identify who is admin or not in any of the two users, whether admin or normal user.

[this is my result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o2YAV.png)

[image: admin the blue chip , normal user the orange chip]

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to separate admin from other registered users?

Comment: You are setting 'condition' based on props outside of the map. Use the mapped user's status to set the chip color.

Comment: Yes it is right @sergeyGubarev ,

Comment: please tell how with a  example @DovRine because I'm new in reactjs

Comment: just use the code that you already posted. Find the condition check, and check the user in the map function instead of using the one set at the top of the render function.

Comment: style={{ backgroundColor: condition ? "#00a6ff" : "#ff8400" , color: 'white', fontWeight: 'bold',}}

Comment: if it's no bother you can write the example code @DovRine

Comment: style={{ backgroundColor: user. isAdmin ? "#00a6ff" : "#ff8400" , color: 'white', fontWeight: 'bold'}}

Comment: it doesn't work bro, change unicolor chips for both session , I will send the idea by pic

Comment: @DovRine in the post I uploaded a pic to see what I want

Comment: @vramh.developer, Did you write the code you posted in the OP? It doesn't seem like you understand it at all.